# Training dataset

Tags: twitter, data-mining, text-classification

I have about 8 million tweets about natural crisis such as earthquakes.
And I am going to a build a model to classify tweets according to their textual content into different categories such as offering help, report injuries, donation, or sympathy. 
**Can you please advise me of training dataset that I can use to train the classifier.**

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

I found these datasets http://crisislex.org/crisis-lexicon.html that contains labelled tweets about crisis